# Oracle: Jobs not found in dba_scheduler_jobs

Tags: oracle, jobs

Using the second query I can find the JOB id. But using the first one it's not present. Why?

```
select *
from dba_scheduler_jobs dj
WHERE dj.job_action LIKE '%Power%02%' AND dj.owner = 'SIUETL';

select *
  FROM dba_jobs dj
 WHERE dj.what LIKE '%Power%02%' AND dj.log_user = 'SIUETL';
```

Comment: can you check your privilege on dba_scheduler_jobs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because DBA_JOBS uses the old (deprecated) DBMS_JOB job scheduling system, whereas DBA_SCHEDULER_JOBS uses the new and shiny DBMS_SCHEDULER.

These two are completely independent.